# Camera screen showing only blank black image

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

I am developing an application which needs iPhone camera access. I am using xcode version 6.3 and swift 1. It was working fine with iOS 8 and currently I updated my iPhone to iOS 9.0.1. And when accessing camera through my application, all I am getting is a blank black screen. This is the sample code I have been using

```
func CameraAction() {
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
}
```

Comment: goto settings -> Photos & Camera. And check your app has access.

Comment: @oldrinmendez I don't see an option to enable or disable camera access for individual apps in settings -> Photos & Camera in iOS 9.0.1

Comment: Having the same issue, was this ever solved?
I dont see an option to enable or disable camera either.

Comment: Starting from iOS7 there is a new key that can be added to the Info.plist: `NSCameraUsageDescription` (Privacy - Camera). You can use it for specifying the reason to access de device's camera. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself. goto setting -> privacy -> camera and enable or disable camera access for individual apps

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to occur when the key: "CFBundleDisplayName" has an empty string value in the Info.plist. I added a value and the black screen issue is now fixed!

Comment: I am not sure about CFBundleDisplayName. But that was not my issue. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I was getting crazy and found this... Saved me, THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

No luck with above workarounds in iOS 11. Noticed that 'Take Photo' is not appearing in **iOS 11 version**, Apple might have removed it as its bug. I did not find an Apple link for official confirmation on this.